# disable a specific warning in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I installed the new QtCreator which comes with the new clang language model and provides lots of useful warnings. However one of them annoys me: `Winconsistent-missing-destructor-override`. How to disable this one and keep the other warnings?

UPDATE: I am talking about the warnings which I get as in-line warnings in the text editor in Qt Creator IDE (which uses Clang toolchain). I am not talking about the warnings produced when compiling the project (which is for example MSVC in my case).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To disable specific warning annotations in the Qt IDE:

Go to *Tools -> Options -> C++ -> Code Model*

Click **Manage** next to *Diagnostic Configuration*

Select **Clang-only checks for almost everything[built-in]**

Click **Copy** on the upper right corner

Go to the copied version of the *Diagnostics Configuration* and append `-Wno-inconsistent-missing-destructor-override` in the text field under the **Clang** tab.

You can read more about configuring the Clang Code Model [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-clang-codemodel.html#configuring-clang-code-model).